# Pass string to Google Chart addRows

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have the following function that generates a Google chart, but it's not working:

```
function drawChart(a) {
          alert(a.test);
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();       
          data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
          data.addRows(a.test);


          var options = {
                             title: 'Company Performance'
                         };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

"a.test" retrieve a string that is the following:

```
test="[['2004', 1000, 400],['2005', 1170, 460],['2006', 660, 1120],['2007', 1030, 540]]";
```

But if i put directly the values in this way

```
data.addRows([['2004', 1000, 400],['2005', 1170, 460],['2006', 660, 1120],['2007', 1030, 540]]);
```

it works.

Could you please help me on understanding where i am wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `addRows` method accepts an array of arrays, not a string, so you need to either change `a.test` into an array or change it into a JSON string and call `JSON.parse` on it:

```
// note that the internal quotes are double-quotes here, as that is required by JSON
var foo = '[["2004", 1000, 400],["2005", 1170, 460],["2006", 660, 1120],["2007", 1030, 540]]';
data.addRows(JSON.parse(foo));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to put your code directly in my function but it is still not working... :-/

Comment: I put it in a fiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/hyRdR/.  Note that to use this method, you would have to change the quotes inside your string from single-quotes to double-quotes in order to be compatible with the JSON spec.

Comment: Thank you!I missed <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of the page and this was the problem!:-)
Now it works!thanks a lot for your help!!!